# how to validate date based on input type text and display the day according to input date in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to validate the data according to day month and year and print the day according to an input value.

```
class Inputdate extends React.Component {
       state={
           inputDate:''
       }
    
     
   render() {
          console.log(this.state)
        return (
          <div>
            <input
                name="date"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
              onChange={(e)=> this.setState({inputDate : e.target.value})}
            />
            <p>{this.state.inputDate}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more context on this? You can give an example of input and output as well.

Comment: input date : 20-02-1986 or 20/02/1986
output : Monday
without using moment js or any library

Comment: `e.target.value.replace('-', '/')` This would give you the expected output

Comment: no no if anyone enters a invalid date like 56-13-0001 it will be wrong right. so i want to validate the date entered irrespective of - and / and want to print the day for the date

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways. I have listed some ways you can validate your date.

## Solution 1

```
function isValidDate(inputDate) {
    return !isNaN(Date.parse(inputDate);
}
```

## Solution 2

```
function isValidDate(inputDate) {
    const date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(19|20)\d{2}$/;
    return date_regex.test(inputDate)
}

function getDay(date) {
  const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  if (isValidDate(date)) {
    const myDate = new Date(date);
    
    return days[myDate.getDay()];
  }
  
  return "Invalid Date"
}

console.log(getDay('12-01-1994'));

console.log(getDay('12-01-0001'));
```

In your case

```
function isValidDate(inputDate) {
    return !isNaN(Date.parse(inputDate);
}
class Inputdate extends React.Component {
       state={
           inputDate:''
       }
    
     
   render() {
          console.log(this.state)
        return (
          <div>
            <input
                name="date"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
              onChange={(e)=> {
                 if(isValidDate(e.target.value)){
                    this.setState({inputDate : e.target.value.replace('-', '/')})
                 }
              }}
            />
            <p>{this.state.inputDate}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: ok and how to print the day for the inputted date

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: the validation is not working properly sir

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: when i m inputting 12-29-0001 it is still printing in my paragraph tag but what i want is if i input a valid date like 12-01-1994 or 12/01/1994 it should print the day of the date like output should be wednesday

Comment: 0001 belongs to anno domini calendar AD  which is wrong year input and even the month cannot be greater than 12

Comment: You cannot have two pattern in your date input either it should be `dd-mm-yyyy` or 'mm-dd-yyyy'. If you try to validate both then it will not be possible. Eg validating this date `01-02-1990` and `02-01-1990`

Comment: In above comments you have given me example of `20-02-1986 or 20/02/1986`

Comment: okay even if i use one format still its taking this input 12/29/0001 which is a wrong validation i guess sir.